# Dormant account in an Israeli bank

Tags: israel, dormant-account

I have an account with Bank Leumi in Israel. I'm not using it; the account has a minimum sum in NIS which is dwindling due to maintenance fees. So, what's going to happen when it reaches zero? There are three options:

1. My account is cancelled by bank.
2. My account keeps accumulating maintenance fees that become a debt.
3. Fees stop but account is not cancelled. (Highly unlikely.)

Different countries use different approaches here. Which one does Israel use?

P.S. Of course, I tried asking the bank itself. Communicating with them from abroad proved fruitless - they keep telling me to visit the exact office I opened the account in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Notice to the Public Re: Credit Balances in Dormant Leumi Accounts](https://english.leumi.co.il/Articles/32953/) (dated 1<sup>st</sup> April 2019):

> We wish to inform you that there are credit balances in the Bank in dormant accounts with a balance of less than NIS 1,000, which were closed as the Bank was unable to locate the owners of the accounts.

it appears that they periodically close accounts whose balances drop below the NIS 1,000 threshold (roughly $280 or £210). Note, that any remaining balance shouldn't be lost (at least at this stage) as the notice continues:

> The Bank has set up a special call center to deal with transferring the balances to the credit of these customers.
>
> In addition, efforts are currently being made to locate the aforementioned account holders.

and gives contact details for people with affected accounts.